# How to restore HDMI audio in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, tv

I use my TV as my main display for my Windows 10 machine, and also as the audio device. This has always worked fine, but on turning on the machine this morning, there is no sound and the TV audio device (CTVE?) has disappeared from the sound menu.

I've checked out some threads on Microsoft's forums [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-hdmi-audio-not-working/293eec79-e0f8-4837-bbd0-341cfc9bd446) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hdmi-output-disappeared-on-laptop-tv-no-longer/9a20554b-8424-484b-ac44-c65566a57e3b) but they are inconclusive, and the basic troubleshooting steps don't help (as reported by most users on the forum).

The device has not been disabled - it's just disappeared. When I try to update drivers I'm told I already have the best ones. I've of course tried restarting the machine, and checking cables are still securely attached. Hyper-V (an apparently problematic service) is not enabled.

I've checked that there have been no Windows Updates, configuration changes, or changes to my physical setup overnight.

Any advice on how to restore my HDMI audio?

Answer (score 0):

So a bit of a non-solution, but in the end performing a hard restart (holding Shift while you do it) restored the playback device. Don't ask me why.